# How can I filter these Elasticsearch aggregations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm using this rails gem:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails

I'm trying to build a facetted navigation where users can filter by color, size, etc.

**I'm setting up my aggs like so (this is the relevant snippet of the code):**

```
    aggs: {
      key: {
        terms: {
          field: "features.key",
          exclude: options[:key] # These are excluded because I want all the aggs that have not been selected, so I can display the remaining aggs for the user.
        },
        aggs: {
          value: {
            terms: {
              field: "features.value",
              exclude: options[:value]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  # These are filtering what the user selects, to return products matching these feature key/value pairs
  __set_filters.(:features, { term: { "key" => options[:key] } })
  __set_filters.(:features, { term: { "value" => options[:value] } })
```

**I'm searching like so:**

`Product.search("", {key: :size, value: :small}`

**This is the gems resulting query object:**

```
=> #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response:0x007fbf38d01ea8
 @klass=
  [PROXY] Product(id: integer, name: string, sku: string, description: text, tenant_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, meta_keywords: string, meta_description: string, base_price_cents: integer, base_price_currency: string, discount_price_cents: integer, discount_price_currency: string, retail_price_cents: integer, retail_price_currency: string, quantity: integer, parent_id: integer),
 @search=
  #<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x007fbf38c81c08
   @definition=
    {:index=>"swift_platform_application_development",
     :type=>"product",
     :body=>
      {:query=>{:bool=>{:should=>[{:multi_match=>{:query=>"Movies", :fields=>["name^10", "features^2", "categories", "description"], :operator=>"and"}}]}},
       :filter=>{:and=>[{:term=>{"key"=>:size}}, {:term=>{"value"=>:small}}, {:term=>{"tenant_id"=>1}}]},
       :aggs=>{:key=>{:terms=>{:field=>"features.key", :exclude=>:size}, :aggs=>{:value=>{:terms=>{:field=>"features.value", :exclude=>:small}}}}}}},
   @klass=
    [PROXY] Product(id: integer, name: string, sku: string, description: text, tenant_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, meta_keywords: string, meta_description: string, base_price_cents: integer, base_price_currency: string, discount_price_cents: integer, discount_price_currency: string, retail_price_cents: integer, retail_price_currency: string, quantity: integer, parent_id: integer),
   @options={}>>
```

**And here is the actual response**

```
[313] pry(main)> a.response["aggregations"]
=> {"key"=>
  {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
   "sum_other_doc_count"=>0,
   "buckets"=>
    [{"key"=>"shape",
      "doc_count"=>41,
      "value"=>
       {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
        "sum_other_doc_count"=>0,
        "buckets"=>
         [{"key"=>"square", "doc_count"=>17},
          {"key"=>"oval", "doc_count"=>14},
          {"key"=>"medium", "doc_count"=>11},
          {"key"=>"green", "doc_count"=>10},
          {"key"=>"large", "doc_count"=>10},
          {"key"=>"round", "doc_count"=>10},
          {"key"=>"blue", "doc_count"=>9},
          {"key"=>"orange", "doc_count"=>7},
          {"key"=>"red", "doc_count"=>6}]}},
     {"key"=>"color",
      "doc_count"=>37,
      "value"=>
       {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0,
        "sum_other_doc_count"=>0,
        "buckets"=>
         [{"key"=>"square", "doc_count"=>14},
          {"key"=>"blue", "doc_count"=>12},
          {"key"=>"oval", "doc_count"=>12},
          {"key"=>"green", "doc_count"=>11},
          {"key"=>"medium", "doc_count"=>10},
          {"key"=>"large", "doc_count"=>8},
          {"key"=>"orange", "doc_count"=>8},
          {"key"=>"red", "doc_count"=>6},
          {"key"=>"round", "doc_count"=>6}]}}]}}
```

So the "key" aggs `shape` and `color` have the same "value" aggs. But I want the `shape` to only include `square, oval, round, etc.` and `color` to only include `red, blue, orange, etc.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an example document in JSON to your answer as an example which has color and shape properties? Without the details I'm doing some guesswork now: It seems you're have one bag `features` in which you're mixing `colors` and `shape` , is that so? I don't think `exclude` does what you expect, it only filters the terms itself but not the array entity as a whole. I *think* you need to split up features into `features_color` and `features_shape` (just the values, not the keys) for that.